# Build knife-rackspace gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to modify a knife-rackspace gem to be able to bootstrap using winrm rather than ssh but i am not able to build the gem. 
I've cloned the knife-rackspace code from https://github.com/opscode/knife-rackspace

but when i try to run rake i get the following error

```
$ rake --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'default'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:142:in `invoke_task'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:9:in `<top (required)>'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/rake:23:in `load'
c:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I a, ,completely new to Ruby so i don t have any clue on what does it mean or how to fix it....
have you got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there's no default Rake task, that you are trying to run. Though I don't think you want to actually run that. If you made some changes to the library and would like to build the gem, try this:

```
$ gem build knife-rackspace.gemspec
```

This should build you a knife-rackspace-0.6.3.gem file.